# Halted upgrade of Ubuntu 17.04, installed updates, and laptop won't start

Tags: upgrade, updates, startup

A few days ago I decided to upgrade Ubuntu. It changed the repositories but I didn't continue it further than that. I stopped the upgrade after it removed certain repos.

Today, I installed the latest updates. There were a lot of them in the Software Updates package.

Now my laptop won't start.

It goes as far as the Ubuntu loading screen, but then the screen goes dark and stays that way.

My laptop uses Nvidia.

How can I fix it so it works?

[edit]

According to a partition manager running on an `16.04` boot disk, it says I installed `17.10`

Comment: How many updates? A dozen? Or hundreds? When you say "won't start", what exactly happens when you try?

Comment: It is probably an issue with your nvidia driver. When your say "there were a lot of (updates) it may be that you did indeed upgrade to 17.10. Try booting an older kernel or if that fails try to boot to recovery mode and take a look at your system and nvidia driver.

Comment: @user535733 The Ubuntu loading screen comes on, then it does something like a fsck, and then darkness

Comment: @Panther It did indeed install 17.10

Comment: 17.10 has issues with nvidia cards, I am not sure if it is the kernel or wayland, probably wayland. gdm uses wayland but you may be able to install kdm or ssdm which will use X , and then log into an X session rather than wayland.

Comment: @Panther Thanks. I don't know how to change my display manager if I can't boot into my system.

Comment: @Panther Booted into safe mode.

Comment: @Panther When I run `dpkg` O get "Temporary failure resolving gb.archive.ubuntu.com"

Comment: @Panther `failsafeX` doesn't work

Comment: I am sorry that did not work. Which nvidia card ?